# Is there any trick to explicitly express my intent to prevent a method from changing its object's fields?

Tags: c#

I want to express my intent as clear as possible. The method `ChangeFields` below is allowed to change the object's fields. How about the opposite in which I want to prevent another method, namely `ReadOnly` from changing the fields?

I know that by default method arguments are immutable -- we cannot change the argument to point to another object --  unless we explicitly use the keyword `ref`.

```
class Foo
{
    public string Text;
    public int Count;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Count = {Count}, Text = {Text}";
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this);
    }
}




class Program
{
    static void ChangeFields(Foo f)
    {
        f.Count = 10;
        f.Text = "Changed";
    }

    static void ChangeObject(ref Foo f)
    {
        f = new Foo { Text = "New object", Count = 100 };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo f = new Foo { Text = "New", Count = 1 };
        f.Display();

        ChangeFields(f);
        f.Display();

        ChangeObject(ref f);
        f.Display();
    }
}
```

## Question

Is there any trick to explicitly express my intent to prevent a method from changing its object's fields?

Comment: Do you mean something like `const` in C++?

Comment: @LouisGo: I am not familiar enough with C++, your guess might be correct.

Comment: You want an explicit expression to tell api user or api developer "This method doesn't change parameter"? Answers to these two use cases might be varied.

Comment: There’s no way to stop some method from changing fields while another is allowed. You could do *none* or *all* by with or without `readonly` keyword.

Comment: This this answering your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826657/4123703

Comment: If you have the public properties/fields in you class, that means they can be rear and changed from anywhere. You can not control the behaviour of the method when you are calling it. If `ChangeFields` method is going to be written by you then you should have it accept `Text` and `Count` parameters. Not the `Foo` parameter. And then you can call this method by doing `ChangeFields(f.Text, f.Count)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
class Foo
{
    public string Text { get; private set;} // This mean only method in Foo can change
    public int Count { get; } // This mean can't change this
}
```

Comment: No no no. You made the `Foo` cannot be changed in other places too.